Which maps from Planescape: Turn of Fortune's Wheel would be most beneficial to have printed out in 1" grid scale?
I will be DMing a Planescape: Turn of Fortune's Wheel campaign soon. Maps in the book are small, and it would be hard to use them for tactical fights and puzzles. The party I will be DMing for likes to fight on a tactical maps, as it takes a lot of guesswork and "I think you think" issues of theater of mind approach.
That said, a PDF with all maps prepared to be printed out on A3 pages is 384 pages long. Printing it in full color would be prohibitively expensive. So which ones should I choose? The ones with fight highly likely are a priority, with ones where fight is inevitable on the top. Second tier are ones with puzzles that can benefit from the grid and exact locations, like the

 levers and doors in the crematorium

I am reading thorough the adventure book now, but it is a lot and I hope for guidance from someone who already played or DMed this adventure.

Print the player version of the first few
If you are playing the campaign from the start, who knows if you ever will get to the end. Just print the maps as the adventure progresses. That way you can also see how important it is, or how well it works.
To start, print the Mortuary Basement, the Caker Tea Party map that is relatively small, and the Fortune's Wheel Casino map. You can clip white cardboard over it with paper clips if there are areas you do not want to reveal, or you can cut it apart and deliver it room by room.
My real advise however is to not print any maps at all. Instead, get a laminated square grid map (you can make your own, or buy one, there are many options; I like the foldable ones better as they are easier to transport), and some ereasable markers, and you are all set. It really takes very little time to sketch out a room on the map if it matters, and you can sketch out the overall map as quickly on graph paper. In my experience, the logistics of juggling lots of maps, room pieces, styrofoam/Lego/plastic walls easily can rival the time to do this.
If you are concerned about how much less impressive graphically this is going to be, I have not experienced that to matter that much for play. Yes, a colorful map is nice eye-candy, but the overall impact on a great game experience is really minor compared to how good you roleplay, narrate, how fast you keep the action going, how fair you adjudicate and so on.

+1000 to laminated square grid and dry (or wet) erase markers.
